# How would I go about creating a user ranked post popularity page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, customization, php

I currently run a music blog using Wordpress as my CMS and i'm looking to redesign the site in the very near future.

Part of my plan for the redesign is to try and integrate a user ranking system for each blog post.

Ideally registered users would be able to upvote or downvote songs (posts), with the results being shown on a separate, dedicated page where viewers could show the most popular tracks from the last day/week/month/year/all-time.

The best analogy would be a hybrid between Reddit and Hypem (or even Stack's system) but hopefully with much less technical proficiency needed for its development.

Are there any plug-ins that may be able to help me develop such an idea? If not could people suggest how I should go about coding it myself? I don't mind taking on such a project but I would love to know how to get started so I'm not wasting time unnecessarily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the plugin "Vote it Up" :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/

Be aware that this plugin was last tested with WordPress 2.8.  That said, it almost does what you want so you could use the code as an inspiration.